# How to run webMethods package from designer to trigger SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, webmethods, sonarlint-eclipse

I am trying to run the webMethods package from designer to trigger SonarQube.
SonarLint is allowing to run a project but not a webMethods package.

For now, I am placing Sonar scanner properties file inside the package and triggering sonar scanner via cmd prompt.

Please help.